# Calculating energy

Tags: java, image, pixel, energy

I am trying to calculate the energy of a pixel using the gradient formula how ever I am encountering a problem, for some reason everything but the edges of the image calculates. For example
   Reading a 6x5 image from the command line the answer should look like this:

```
     57685   50893   91370   25418   33055   37246
     15421   56334   22808   54796   11641   25496
     12344   19236   52030   17708   44735   20663
     17074   23678   30279   80663   37831   45595
     32337   30796    4909   73334   40613   36556
```

but i'm getting

```
     195075  195075  195075  195075  195075  195075
     195075  56334   22808   54796   11641   195075
     195075  19236   52030   17708   44735   195075
     195075  23678   30279   80663   37831   195075
     195075  195075  195075  195075  195075  195075
```

my energy method

```
     public double energy(int x, int y) {

    if (x < 0 || x >= width()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("x must be between 0 and " + (width()-1));
    }
    if (y < 0 || y >= height()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("y must be between 0 and " + (height()-1));
    }
    // border case
    if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == (width() - 1) || y == (height() - 1)) {
        return 3 * 255 * 255;
    }
    return Gradient(x, y);
}
public double Gradient(int x, int y) {
    Color c1 = picture.get(x-1, y);
    Color c2 = picture.get(x+1, y);
    Color c3 = picture.get(x, y - 1);
    Color c4 = picture.get(x, y + 1);
    double deltaX = Math.pow(c2.getRed() - c1.getRed(), 2) +
            Math.pow(c2.getBlue() - c1.getBlue(), 2) +
            Math.pow(c2.getGreen() - c1.getGreen(), 2);

    double deltaY = Math.pow(c4.getRed() - c3.getRed(), 2) +
            Math.pow(c4.getBlue() - c3.getBlue(), 2) +
            Math.pow(c4.getGreen() - c3.getGreen(), 2);
    return deltaX + deltaY;
}
```

Comment: I imagine it's a problem with your code.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: sorry for being vague, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this condition in your code:

```
// border case
if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == (width() - 1) || y == (height() - 1)) {
    return 3 * 255 * 255;
}
```

This ends up returning `195075` for all of the edge points.

I don't know what formula you used to get the edge point energies in your desired answer, but you should use the same formula in your code instead of just returning `195075`.